# Problem with concatenate function in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I am trying to recreate something like this picture:
[Financial Year in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcj4Y.jpg)

But I just found out that the **cell B7 does not work**, the **cell B7** contains the formula:

> =IF($A$3="Financial Year",((CONCATENATE(B9,$C$3))-DAY(CONCATENATE(B9,$C$3))+1),EDATE(Summary!$C$15,-11))

In the above **A3 cell** is the one where I choose **Financial Year**, **B9** is month **January**, **C3** is the cell with the calendar year **2020** and the **Summary tab** is the picture here:[Summary Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbAOP.png) where cell **C15** is the starting date with the formula: **=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1**

**Error I am getting from Cell B7**:

> Function Day Parameter 1 expects number values. But "January" is a text and cannot be coerced to a number

Comment: What is the result of CONCATENATE(B9,$C$3))+1)? Looks like that needs to be a number, but  it is returning a string according to the error you provided.

Comment: B9 is January and C3 is 2020, so concatenate of it should be January 2020 I think

Comment: I'd suggest breaking your statement apart to make sure each function returns what you expect, if B9=january and c3=1, then concatenate(b9,c3) = january2020, and day(concatenate(b9,c3)) = 1. Try double checking this is what you get.

Comment: Sorry was out for a while! I checked day(concatenate(b9,c3)), and it is giving me back 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have had a temporary condition where C3 was blank.  It is easy to run several tests to see what Day does with "Strings".

=Day("January" & 2020) returns 1, the day value of the first day of January.

=Day("January2020") also returns 1, even though "January2020" is clearly a string.
=Day("Nothing2020") returns the error you saw, where DAY expects a numeric value.

If the string is one that Google Sheets recognises as a date type, it treats it as a number value for those functions requiring that.

"January2020" is seen as a valid date, but "January" is not.

Your error indicates to me that C3 was blank at the time of the error, since it said {
**"January"** is a text, and cannot.....} .
Let us know if you still have the error situation.  If so, please share a copy of your sheet.